# Error computing determinant of a $4\times 4$ matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

I am trying to compute the determinant of

$$C = \begin{bmatrix}-2 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 3 & 1 & -3 \\ -2 & -2 & -1 & 2 \\ 0 & 2 & 3 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

I first did the row operation $R_3 \leftarrow R_1-R_3$ so it doesn't change the determinant. So you want the determinant of:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}-2 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 3 & 1 & -3 \\ 0 & 5 & 3 & -1 \\ 0 & 2 & 3 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

and this simplifies to the $-2$ times the determinant of:

$$C = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 & -3 \\  5 & 3 & -1 \\  2 & 3 & 1  \end{bmatrix}$$

And this $3\times 3$ matrix has determinant of $-16$ so the determinant of $C$ is $(-2)\cdot (-16) = 32$. However, the book says that the answer is $-32$ and not $32$.

Any hints where the negative comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that  the determinant does not change if you add to a row a linear combination of the others.

You should replace $R_3$ with $R_3-R_1$. Then you obtain
$$\begin{bmatrix}-2 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 3 & 1 & -3 \\ 0 & -5 & -3 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 & 3 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
and the determinant of 
$$\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 & -3 \\  -5 & -3 & 1 \\  2 & 3 & 1  \end{bmatrix}$$
is just the opposite of $-16$ (your previous computation).

Comment: I did replace $R_3 \leftarrow R_1-R_3$. However, I am getting negative the correct answer not the correct answer!

Comment: @AspiringMat I say replace it with $R_3-R_1$

Comment: Sorry I am a little confused. What's the difference here? Why would it change the determinant if we are allowed to add multiple of any row to another?

Comment: @AspiringMat  Adding to row $R_3$ a linear combination of the others means that you can replace $R_3$ with $R_3+a_1R_1+a_2R_2+a_4R_4$.

Comment: I see. So essentially I did $R_3 \leftarrow R_1-R_3$ which is two operations one that is yours and one replacing $R_3$ by $-R_3$ which we should inturn compensate for by multiplying the $3\times 3$ matrix determinant by -1 correct?

Comment: @AspiringMat Yes, that's right.